# Summary from within the Table having same key in Database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good Day!

Would there be a simple but effective SQL syntax to summarize data from within a table based on Primary Key?

For example, I have the table SampleTable1 on database SampleDB:

```
      |PermaID   |Name_of_Person | Cash    |
      |111       |Michael        | 200     |
      |111       |Mikel          | 100     |
      |222       |Kid            | 200     |
      |222       |Kidd           | 200     |
      |222       |Kidd           | 200     |
      |222       |Kid            | 200     |
      |333       |Him            | 100     |
      |333       |Him            | 200     |
```

Would there be an SQL string(s) that would output the summary based on **PermaID**, and not on the Name? :

```
      |PermaID   |Name_of_Person | Cash    |
      |111       |Michael        | 300     |
      |222       |Kid            | 800     |
      |333       |Him            | 300     |
```

Assume that the Correct name is the First Name SQL detected. ..And that there are actually more than three columns in my actual table.

..If there aren't, should I output in my UI and then summarize myself via looping on the arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the first record name to be selected

```
;with Cte as( Select PermaID  ,Name_of_Person,Cash, C=ROW_NUMBER()
          over(partition by PermaID   order by PermaID   )
          From SampleTable1 
          )
Select Cte.PermaID   ,Cte.Name_of_Person,SUM(T.Cash)
from Cte Inner Join SampleTable1 T On T.PermaID =Cte.PermaID   
Where C=1
Group By  Cte.PermaID ,Cte.Name_of_Person
```

Fiddle sample [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/864e4/1)

Comment: The Fiddle helped a lot. Thank you very much!

Comment: It works, even if I have many columns that what I've stated above.

Comment: My apologies, when I tried it in my actual table, an Error Appeared: (The multi-part identifier "TableName.FieldName" could not be bound.) How do I resolve this? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the result you are looking for

```
SELECT PermaID,MIN(Name_of_Person),SUM(Cash)
FROM SampleTable1
GROUP BY PermaID
```

Comment: MIN(Name_of_Person) is not necessary the first

Comment: It says "Invalid in the Select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." My apologies my table contains more than 3 columns. will update the question.

Comment: @Raj Should I simply include all Columns in the select statement? (the problem is there are more than 30 columns in this particular table...)

Comment: *"Correct name is the First Name SQL detected"* will using `MIN()` satisfy that??

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (PermaID INT,Name varchar(10),Cash INT)
INSERT INTO @t (PermaID,Name,Cash)values (111,'Michael',200)
INSERT INTO @t (PermaID,Name,Cash)values (111,'Michae',200)
INSERT INTO @t (PermaID,Name,Cash)values (222,'Raju',300)
INSERT INTO @t (PermaID,Name,Cash)values (222,'Raj',300)

;WITH CTE AS 
(select distinct PermaID,Name,Cash from @t)
select distinct PermaID,MAX(Name),SUM(Cash) 
from CTE
GROUP BY PermaID
```

Comment: *"Correct name is the First Name SQL detected"*